# Find partition size using df and awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How can I make this better / more efficient:

```
df -h | grep /partition | awk '{print $3}' | awk '{$0=substr($0,1,length($0)-1); print $0}'
```

This prints the size of /partition (removing the last character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one pipe is enough:

```
df -h | awk 'NR > 1 && /partition/ {print substr($3,1,length($3)-1)}'
```

Comment: Yes I had forgot about NR.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` instead of `awk` again:

```
df -h | grep "/partition" | awk '{print $3}' | sed -e 's,[A-Z]$,,'
```

Keep in mind that this (and your one-liner) does not print the size of the partition, but the size **used**.

Comment: This will break if the size multiplier for the partition is something other than "G". (The letters "M" and "T" certainly are possibilities, at the very least.)

Comment: Yikes, yes. Modified.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation, telling `df` to do the filtering, and using `awk`s `gensub()` instead:

```
df -h /partition | awk 'NR > 1 { print gensub("G$", "", "", $3) }'
```